# How to open a .NVG-CHT-BIN file

Tags: diagram, file-type, flowchart

I have a file that appears to be a flow chart, however, it is in the format of XXX.NVG-CHT-BIN

I have tried every different notepad program I have, Microsoft Visio, pdf viewers, image viewers, and even some sketchy looking programs off google that claimed they could open this type of file.

I absolutely can't figure out how to open this file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in Notepad++ and check if you can read something. Maybe it is stored in an XML scheme or similiar.

I guess that the extension could mean navigation chart or something, where did you get it from?

Otherwise check the File Signature, a way to do this is described here: https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html